# How to create multidimensional array in nested loop while?

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, nested-loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have nested loop while and I'd like to create multidimensional array with some datas from these loops
Output should be look like:

```
'productId'=>1
'productImg'=>some_url
'productContent'=> subarray(
     'question1'=>value1
     'answer1'=>value1,
     'question2'=value2,
     'question2'=>value2
)
```

My code with nested while loops

```
    if (have_rows('dodaj_pytania_do_produktu')):

        while (have_rows('dodaj_pytania_do_produktu')) : the_row();
            $counter = 1;
            $productID = get_sub_field('nazwa_produktu_faq');
            $productImage = get_sub_field('dodaj_zdjecie');
            $productsData[] = array(
                'productId' => $productID,
                'productImg' => $productImage,

            );
            $product = wc_get_product($productID);
            $productName = $product->get_title();
            // Loop over sub repeater rows.
            if (have_rows('dodaj_pytanie_i_odpowiedz')):
                while (have_rows('dodaj_pytanie_i_odpowiedz')) : the_row();
                    $question = get_sub_field('dodaj_pytanie');
                    $answer = strip_tags(get_sub_field('dodaj_odpowiedz'));
                    $productsData[] = array(
                        'productDesc'=> array(
                        'question' => $question,
                        'answer' => $answer
                        )
                    );
                endwhile;
            endif;
        endwhile;
    else :
        echo "brak faq";
    endif;

    ?>
```

Now my output create wrong subarray not creating a subarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hurry to create the array, wait till you have everything, so create the new array at the end of the outer loop, and build a temp array for the `productContent` array, put it all together at then end

```
if (have_rows('dodaj_pytania_do_produktu')):

    while (have_rows('dodaj_pytania_do_produktu')) : the_row();

        $productID = get_sub_field('nazwa_produktu_faq');
        $productImage = get_sub_field('dodaj_zdjecie');
        
        $product = wc_get_product($productID);
        $productName = $product->get_title();
        // Loop over sub repeater rows.
        if (have_rows('dodaj_pytanie_i_odpowiedz')):
            $x = 1; // counter
            $pc = [];
            while (have_rows('dodaj_pytanie_i_odpowiedz')) : 
                the_row();
                $question = get_sub_field('dodaj_pytanie');
                $answer = strip_tags(get_sub_field('dodaj_odpowiedz'));

                // build the inner loop content here
                $pc[] = ["question$x" => $question,
                         "answer$x" => $answer
                         ];
                $x++;
            endwhile;

            // put it all together here
            $productsData[] = [
                        'productId' => $productID,
                        'productImg' => $productImage,
                        'productContent = $pc
                ];

        endif;
    endwhile;
else :
    echo "brak faq";
endif;
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Now best to go through this with nested foreach? I would like each product to display its content separately